# external disk formated with NTFS not working on Mac

Tags: mac, external-disk, disk-format, ntfs, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hard drive read only access with Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10628/hard-drive-read-only-access-with-mac)

I bought new 1 TB **WD My Passport** and format it with NTFS on windows XP. and now when I connect it on mac, I see the drive but I cant add files to it.

what is the issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the default NTFS driver that comes with OS X is read only.  You will need to purchase a NTFS driver in order to write to the drive.

Comment: I am not particularly interested in any file format I want to take back up from my two MacBooks and one Windows. When I buy this external disk, it says, format first to use it on mac. how I can use it for both? probably now, instead of re-format it again may be I will try to get NTFS driver for mac

Comment: Use Fat32 instead of NTFS and both should be able to write to it.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the latest release of [OSXFUSE](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/40156/osxfuse) - check [their wiki page](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/NTFS-3G) for more information on using NTFS-3G.